# How to take screenshot under Wayland?

Tags: wayland

I want to write a simple tool that will take screenshots at **Wayland**.
Am I right in my understanding that it would be completely different from Xorg?
Could anybody give me any examples?

Answer (score 7):

Your question is a bit underspecified. You don't need to write a tool as long as you use the reference compositor `Weston` for `Wayland`. It has this feature built in. You can use `Super + S` to take a screenshot and `Super + R` to record a video in `*.wcap` form which you can then convert to a `*.webm` video.

If you should really be interested in writing such a tool then you should look at `Weston`'s source code here: http://cgit.freedesktop.org/wayland/weston and find the relevant parts.

Answer (score 3):

Yes screenshotting works completely different under wayland than under Xorg.

> By design, Wayland is a lot more secure than X11 and does not allow one application to capture the content of other applications' windows, meanignath a X11 based screenshot tool cannot work underWayland/Xwayland.

https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=98672

Sorry I cannot tell you how it is different, just that it is different.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use shutter but it fails with Wayland.

gnome-screenshot works with Wayland but in itself is clunky when it comes to rename files straight after grabbing.

I made 2 scripts: *shut.sh*

```
#!/bin/sh
# call me shut.sh
gnome-screenshot -a -f /path/to/temp/grabcache.png
gnome-terminal -e "bash grabname.sh"
```

and *grabname.sh*

```
#!/bin/sh
# call me grabname.sh
read -p "Name for grab? " grab
cp /path/to/temp/grabcache.png /where/you/want/it/$grab.png
nautilus /path/to/temp
```

Now define a hot key to run *shut.sh* . You will need to specify the exact paths to each script unless you save the scripts to a location in your $PATH variable for the shell.

Then, when you press your key, a cross-hair will appear on the screen for you to select a grab target. This saves grabcache.png to /path/to/temp.

When done, terminal will open and ask you for a file name to copy grabcache.png to $grab in /where/you/want/it. Then, nautilus should open to show you the new renamed grab. If nautilus is already open, you may have to ALT-TAB to it manually.